# Why is a struct field borrowed longer than expected

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Consider the following program. Each element should hold references to elements in the container that already existed at the time it was added.

```rust
struct Element<'a> {
    previous: Vec<&'a Element<'a>>,
}

struct Container<'a> {
    elements: Vec<Element<'a>>,
}

impl <'a>Container<'a> {
    fn new() -> Container<'a> {
        Container{elements: Vec::new()}
    }

    fn add(&'a mut self) -> &'a Element {
        let previous = self.elements.iter().collect();
        let element = Element{previous: previous};
        self.elements.push(element);
        &self.elements[self.elements.len() - 1]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut _c = Container::new();
}
```

This fails with the error

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.elements` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> nested.rs:17:9
   |
9  | impl <'a>Container<'a> {
   |       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
15 |         let previous = self.elements.iter().collect();
   |                        --------------------
   |                        |
   |                        immutable borrow occurs here
   |                        argument requires that `self.elements` is borrowed for `'a`
16 |         let element = Element{previous: previous};
17 |         self.elements.push(element);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

But why is self.elements borrowed for `'a`? I would expect it would no longer be borrowed after the `collect()` is done. I'd expect that each element that was in `self.elements` would be borrowed immutably because of their references now stored in `element.previous`. But `self.elements` should be free to be mutated now.

Comment: There's no functional difference a reference to `self.elements` vs a reference to the elements in it. With your code as-is, `.push` could reallocate the entire vector making all the references in `previous` point at invalid memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

The error is : cannot borrow `self.elements` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

```rust
// this is borrow self.selements
let previous:Vec<&Element> = self.elements.iter().collect();
```

`previous` is borrow from self.elements as immutable,

`self.elements.push(element);` `use self.elements` as mutable, you can't use mutable and immutable both